# Finding an element for selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to find an element within a site, it is a Div class but the usual method is not working

```
div class ="subTabText"> Once Off < /div >
```

I have tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'Once Off')]")
```

but it cannot find it

Comment: You are looking for `class` to contain `Once Off` but the class is `subTabText`.

Comment: The problem is there is # buttons with the same class name only difference between the 3 is where it says "Once Off'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the text "Once Off" is unique try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Once Off')]")
```